# Java project method/if statement problems

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, boolean, project

I'm having a bit of problem with the `getCost` method in this code (I'll paste it below) and really need a response as soon as possible since this is due by midnight tomorrow.  So the problem is that it says the things on the other side of the == are not valid, I mean the GRO, Gro, gro, SAL, Sal, and sal.  For this code I have as user input a destination. Then I calculate the travel cost based on this input, and I'm also supposed to provide a free child ticket for every adult ticket, but I'm not sure how to do that at all.  I'm sure what to do with the second method at all but it's required for the project so it has to be there.  Thanks for any and all help.

```
import java.util.*;

public class HolidayTravel {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Thank you for choosing the Holiday Travel Special!");
        System.out.println("All trips depart from and return to Raleigh, NC, and");
        System.out.println("must take place between Nov 1, 2014 and Jan 15, 2015.");
        System.out.println("When prompted, please enter your destination:");
        System.out.println("GRO (Greensboro), SAL (Salisbury), or CLT (Charlotte),");
        System.out.println("your departure/return dates, and the number of adult,");
        System.out.println("student, and child ticketes you would like to purchase.");
        System.out.println("Destination (GRO, SAL, CLT): ");
        Scanner dest = new Scanner(System.in);
        String destination = dest.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Departure month (11, 12, 1): ");
        Scanner mth = new Scanner(System.in);
        int departureMonth = mth.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Departure Day: ");
        Scanner d = new Scanner(System.in);
        int departureDay = d.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Return month (11, 12, 1): ");
        Scanner rM = new Scanner(System.in);
        int returnMonth = rM.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Return Day: ");
        Scanner rD = new Scanner(System.in);
        int returnDay = rD.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Number of Adult Tickets: ");
        Scanner aT = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberOfAdultTickets = d.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Number of Student Tickets: ");      
        Scanner sT = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberOfStudentTickets = d.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Number of Child Tickets: ");        
        Scanner cT = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberOfChildTickets = d.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("Cost of tickts: %f\n", getCost (destination, numberOfAdultTickets, numberOfStudentTickets, numberOfChildTickets));
}
//Return true if the departure/return dates are valid dates between Nov 1 and Jan 15
//and the departure date occurs before or is the same as the return date
//Return false otherwise 
//public static boolean areValidDates (int departureMonth, int departureDay, int returnMonth, int returnDay){

//}


//Calculates and returns cost of tickets based on destination, price of adult and child tickets,
//student discount, and with one free child ticket for each adult ticket purchase
//Throws an IllegalArgumentException if destination is invalid or number of tickets < 0
    public static int getCost (String destination, int numberOfAdultTickets, int numberOfStudentTickets, int numberOfChildTickets) {
        if (destination == GRO || Gro || gro){
        double gCost = (numberOfAdultTickets*30.00) + (numberOfStudentTickets*(30.00-5.00)) + (numberOfChildTickets*20);
    }else if(destination == SAL || Sal || sal){
        double sCost = (numberOfAdultTickets*55.00) + (numberOfStudentTickets*(55.00-5.00)) + (numberOfChildTickets*45);
    }else{
        double cCost = (numberOfAdultTickets*60.00) + (numberOfStudentTickets*(60.00-5.00)) + (numberOfChildTickets*50);
    }       
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to do your comparison like this:

```java
  public static int getCost (String destination, int numberOfAdultTickets, int numberOfStudentTickets, int   numberOfChildTickets) {
    if (destination.equals(GRO) || destination.equals(Gro) || destination.equals(gro)){
        double gCost = (numberOfAdultTickets*30.00) + (numberOfStudentTickets*(30.00-5.00)) + (numberOfChildTickets*20);
    }else if(destination.equals(SAL) || destination.equals(Sal) || destination.equals(sal)){
        double sCost = (numberOfAdultTickets*55.00) + (numberOfStudentTickets*(55.00-5.00)) + (numberOfChildTickets*45);
    }else{
        double cCost = (numberOfAdultTickets*60.00) + (numberOfStudentTickets*(60.00-5.00)) + (numberOfChildTickets*50);
    }
```

I hope GRO, Gro, gro, SAL, Sal and sal are variables of the type String. If not put "" between them, like this: "GRO" and so on...

Comment: Yeah my problem is that I get an error that says "GRO cannot be resolved to a variable" and the same thing for all the others and I'm not really sure what to do with that.

Comment: Where you declare these variables?

Comment: Ok so I got everything worked out with the getCost method, except for how to give one free child ticket for every adult ticket, but now I'm really not sure how to write the boolean method to check if the dates entered fall between 11/1/14 and 1/15/15.

Comment: I also need to do this    "If the user enters an invalid value for the destination or a number of adult/student/child tickets that is negative, the program should print an error message as soon as the error occurs and quit. If the user enters an invalid departure month, departure day, return month, return day or a departure date that occurs after the return date, the program should print an error message after both dates have been entered and then quit. 
HINT: The statement System.exit(1); will cause the program to quit with a status of 1 indicating an error condition.